# Default value of delegates inside classes

Tags: c#, delegates

```
using System;

public delegate void Printer(string s);

class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Printer p = new Printer(delegate {});
        p+= myPrint;
        p("Hello");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }

    public static void myPrint(string s)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

It seems as if I have to initialize a delegate with an empty anonymous function to be able to use `+=` later on. When I omit the `new` clause, `p` gets to be `null` and `+=` doesn't work, which makes sense.

Now, when I have a class with a delegate instance, I can do the following:

```
using System;

public delegate void Printer(string s);

class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A a = new A();
        a.p += myPrint;
        a.p("Hello");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }

    public static void myPrint(string s)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}


class A {
    public Printer p;
}
```

Why is this allowed? Is there a default value for the delegate instance `p`? It can't be `null` because then I would not be able to assign it a new callback using `+=`. I have tried to search for this problem with the keywords `"default value for delegates"` and found nothing. Also, sorry if the question if too basic.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Delegates are reference types, so the default value is `null`.

However, variables (unlike fields) are not initialized by default:

```
Printer p;
p += myPrint; // doesn't work: uninitialized variable
```

You need to initialize the variable before you can use it:

```
Printer p = null;
p += myPrint;
```

or

```
Printer p;
p = null;
p += myPrint;
```

---

Note that for delegates (but not events!)

```
p += myPrint;
```

is shorthand for

```
p = (Printer)Delegate.Combine(p, new Printer(myPrint));
```

Comment: So, it is null after all. damn.

Comment: You can also use `p = myPrint`.

Comment: And you can also use `p = p + myPrint;` or `p = myPrint + p;`, and this will work (and not be thread-safe) even if `p` is a (field-like) event defined by the same class/struct. The semantic of `+=`, when `p` is an event defined by this class/struct, was changed in C# 4 (2010).