# instantiate and initalialize the delegate

Tags: c#, delegates

I have a quick question about coding delegates.

Why do you have to

```
pf = t.Print;  //instantiate and initialize the delegate.
```

code

```
delegate void PrintFunction();

    public class Test
    {
        public void Print()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Print 1 --instance");
        }

        public static void Print1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Print 2 -- static");
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Test t = new Test();
            PrintFunction pf;
            pf = t.Print;  //instantiate and intialize the delegate

            pf += Test.Print1;
            pf += t.Print;


            if (null != pf)
            {
                pf();
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("delegate is empty");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Delegates are immutable reference types, their default value is null. The default constructor for the delegate accepts a method that matches its signature.

So you can do this:

```
var pf = new PrintFunction(Test.Print1);
pf += t.Print;
```

Or:

```
var pf = Test.Print1;
pf += t.Print;
```

Or:

```
var pf = null;
pf += Test.Print1;
pf += t.Print;
```

### Edit:

Source that Delegates are reference types: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx)

> A reference type contains a pointer to another memory location that
>   holds the data. Reference types include the following:

- String.
- All arrays, even if their elements are value types
- Class types, such as Form
- **Delegates**

Comment: Delegates are value types, not reference types. Or, perhaps better put, they have value-type semantics, even though they are referencing methods.

Comment: @Enigmativity are you sure ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/10710914/3185569 and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx

Comment: @Enigmativity What I know is that Delegates are immutable reference types.

Comment: `Delegates are value types, not reference types.` - nonsense.

Comment: @user3185569 - Sorry, I over-stated it. They have value-type semantics, but are reference types. Just like strings. When I wrote the first sentence I had in my mind their behaviour - which is why I followed up with the "perhaps better put" sentence. But I stand corrected.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to call the code `pf = t.Print;`. It is perfectly acceptable to write `pf = null;`.

If you remove the line `pf = t.Print;` you'll just discover that the compiler is giving you the error "CS0165 Use of unassigned local variable 'pf'".

This is no different than if you wrote the code:

```
bool flag;

if (flag)
{
}
```

It's nothing to do with it being a delegate. It's just a compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

so you have to initialize the delegate the first before you call it, like when calling a class. Also the delegate signature has to match the method that is calling the delegate.

Thanks everyone for the help.
Should of coped it before i posted the question.

Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

By default delegate value is null you should initialize it to something and then use it or add other methods. In your sample there will be 2 times called t.Print and one time Test.Print1.

Good practice is to initialuize delegate to nullable object and then use it without any null checking like below.

```
PrintFunction pf = () => {};
pf += Print1;
pf += Print;
pf += Print1;
pf();
```

Comment: What is a "nullable object"? Also, there would be nothing stopping some code calling `pf = null` and thus forcing you to do null-checking again. It is good practice to do null-checking. It is not good practice to initialize a delegate to `() => { }`.

Comment: Nullable object is a pattern to avoid unnessasery using of null (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern#C.23). There is a bunch of problems with null checking, the biggest one is concurrency. It is not so simple to make thread safe null check. Talking about hand initialization to null, yes it is possible but it's a rare case. In that case, I would recommend use runtime contracts to avoid it.